# How to approach unit test for cakephp

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp

I am trying to wrap my head around unit testing for cakephp and I am wondering if someone can offer some input in how to write a test for a particular controller method:

```
public function paymentmethod() {

    $this->layout='dashboard';
    $billingaddressInfo = $this->Dashboard->find('all',array('fields' => array('Address_book_id','first_name','last_name'),'conditions' => array('Dashboard.customer_id' => $this->Session->read('customer_id'),'address_type'=>'1')));
    $billingaddress = array();
    if(is_array($billingaddressInfo) && count($billingaddressInfo) > 0) {
        foreach($billingaddressInfo as $key=>$value) {
            $billingaddress[$value['Dashboard']['Address_book_id']] = $value['Dashboard']['first_name'].' '.$value['Dashboard']['last_name'];
        }   
    }
    $this->set('billingaddress',$billingaddress);

    $fullbillingaddress = $this->Dashboard->find('all',array('fields' => array('Address_book_id','customer_id','first_name','last_name','address_line_1','address_line_2','city','state','country','zipcode'),
                                    'conditions' => array('Dashboard.customer_id' =>$this->Session->read('customer_id'))));

    $this->set('fullbillingaddress',$fullbillingaddress);   
    $shippingaddress = $this->Dashboard->find('list',array('fields' => array('first_name'),'conditions' => array('Dashboard.customer_id' => $this->Session->read('customer_id'),'address_type'=>'2')));

    $this->set('shippingaddress',$shippingaddress);

    $this->loadModel('Paymentmethod');

    if(!empty ($this->request->data)) {     
        $getpaymentform = $this->request->data['Paymentmethod'];            
        $getpaymentform['card_number'] = $this->encryptCard($getpaymentform['card_number']);            
        if($this->request->data['Paymentmethod']['is_default']==1) {                
            $this->Paymentmethod->updateAll(array('is_default'=>'0'),array('Paymentmethod.customer_id' =>$this->Session->read('customer_id')));
        }
        $this->Paymentmethod->save($getpaymentform);

    }
    $paymentdata = $this->Paymentmethod->find('all',array('conditions' => array('Paymentmethod.customer_id' =>$this->Session->read('customer_id'))));
    $this->set('paymentdata',$paymentdata);
    $this->render();

    if(!empty ($this->request->data)) {
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'paymentmethod')); 
    }           
}
```

I'm really looking for suggestions on which parts of the method to test and what to assert, and I'm not looking for any one to write code, but just an experienced assessment of how you would approach this.  I am very new to it, and would greatly appreciate some input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Break up the parts of your code to make them testable individually

Moving your 'find' actions to the Models would be a good start, that way you could test the individual parts of the action.

For example;

```
class Dashboard extends AppModdel
{
    
    public function getBillingAddress($customerId)
    {
        $billingaddressInfo = $this->find('all',
            array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'Address_book_id',
                    'first_name',
                    'last_name',
                ),
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Dashboard.customer_id' => $customerId,
                    'Dashboard.address_type' => 1,
                ),
            )
        );
    
        $billingaddress = array();
        if(is_array($billingaddressInfo) && count($billingaddressInfo) > 0) {
            foreach($billingaddressInfo as $key=>$value) {
                $billingaddress[$value['Dashboard']['Address_book_id']] = $value['Dashboard']['first_name'].' '.$value['Dashboard']['last_name'];
            }   
        }
    
        return $billingaddress;
    }
}
```

(Note: using a virtualField would probably be a lot easier to do this, but that is off topic for this question)

And, inside your controller, just:

```
$customerId = $this->Session->read('customer_id');
$billingAddress = $this->Dashboard->getBillingAddress($customerId);
```

Not only will moving that code to your Model result in cleaner code (see my example), you'll also be able to test the `getBillingAddress()` method separate from the other code.

To further learn how/what to unit-test, be sure to check the source code of CakePHP itself. Inside the lib/Cake/test directory, you can find the unit-tests of Cake itself, which contain valuable information on how to test certain parts of your application (e.g. How to test a Model, a Controller, a Component etc)

Comment: Thanks alot.  That's a great example.  Would you recommend testing for  the redirection at the end too, or should that be refactored too?

Comment: You should test what is important to test (and depends on your situation). However, things like `$this->encryptCard()` really look like data-related, so should not be part of a Controller. Furthermore, you're manually calling `render()`, before you're doing a redirect, so I wonder if the redirect will actually work as expected?

Comment: Great thanks for your input.  I just inherited the code, and just need ed some fresh eyes on it.

Comment: @DevatoTech glad I could help. Good luck with your project!